QGIS Processing - select by attribute (or expression) syntax
Using the QGIS Processing framework, I have a set of points that I would like to buffer. I need apply different buffer radii to different 'sets' within my points, based on their name.
At a high level, the model is:
Input points > select > 3 x buffer operations based on different radii > merge the buffer polygons > dissolve > output
I'm trying to use the processing Vector Selection toool - 'Select by attribute' - with the following settings:

The desired outcome is that only some points are selected for buffering. The current output is that all points are selected and buffered.
I've also tried the 'Select by Expression' tool using the expression left("ID,2), = 'BH' with no success.
I think my syntax is incorrect for the select tools.  Anyone able to shine some light on this?
Actual values in the Point table include:



PointID
east
north
elevation
depth




BH01
123
321
987
15


BH02
234
432
944
10


BH04
345
432
988
19


TP01
456
543
987
11


TP02
567
654
988
3




can you add some examples of your ID values?

also left("ID,2), = 'BH' has a missing "

Sorry @Ian - that was my typo when entering the code into SO. Actual expression is QGIS has correct punctuation.
